# How to debug error "Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol"

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I created an app (api_tests) that uses a library (libstorage.so) that linked to oracle occi library (libocci.so.12.1) and compiled it. 
When I run this app, I get an error:

```
api_tests
api_tests: symbol lookup error: ./libstorage.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6oracle4occi11Environment17createEnvironmentENS1_4ModeEPvPFS3_S3_mEPFS3_S3_S3_mEPFvS3_S3_E
```

However this library with this symbol exists in the current directory:

```
ls | grep libocci
libocci.so*
libocci.so.11.1*
libocci.so.12.1*

nm libocci.so.12.1 | grep _ZN6oracle4occi11Environment17createEnvironmentENS1_4ModeEPvPFS3_S3_mEPFS3_S3_S3_mEPFvS3_S3_E
0000000000097e70 T _ZN6oracle4occi11Environment17createEnvironmentENS1_4ModeEPvPFS3_S3_mEPFS3_S3_S3_mEPFvS3_S3_E
0000000000125014 r _ZN6oracle4occi11Environment17createEnvironmentENS1_4ModeEPvPFS3_S3_mEPFS3_S3_S3_mEPFvS3_S3_E$$LSDA
```

The current path is added to LD_LABRARY_PATH:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./:/usr/vacpp/bin/../lib:/lib
```

I'm wondering what can be wrong with my library and how I can debug the issue?

Update: 
It looks like this library was not linked (at least ldd doesn't show this dependency). I guess it was mistake in makefile and it was compiled but failes in runtime.

Comment: `ldd ./libstorage.so` ?

Comment: `ls -l ./libocci*` ?

Answer (score 19):

> `nm libocci.so.12.1`

There are two problems with above command:

1. You don't know whether `libocci.so.12.1` is actually getting loaded into your process. To answer the "which libocci is getting loaded", run with `LD_DEBUG=libs`.
2. Just because the symbol is present in the symbol table of `libocci.so.12.1` doesn't mean that it's available for dynamic linking. It *must* be available in the *dynamic* symbol table, which you can examine with `nm -D libocci.so.12.1`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It looks like this library was not linked (at least ldd doesn't show this dependency). I guess it was mistake in makefile and it was compiled but failes in runtime.

Comment: What was the mistake in makefile and how to rectify it. Even for me the dynamic linking is not happening. 
when I run 
$> nm -D libcusolver.so.8.0 
I get 
nm: 'libcusolver.so.8.0' no such file or directory

Comment: Thanks for the LD_DEBUG=libs tip. For me, the problem was I was linking the wrong copy of the shared library which of course did not have the symbol my executable was expecting.