# Why "symbol lookup error", "undefined symbol" when the symbol exists

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

This was originally [a PySide2 bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1278), but after a bit of debugging following 
[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38799192), I think it might be a general c++ problem, regardless what the application and the undefined symbol really is.

When I run `/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide2/designer` and close it, it crashes with

```
/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide2/designer:
  symbol lookup error: /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide2/designer:
  undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

But this should not have happened. First, the system libstdc++ is indeed loaded:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs pyside2-designer 2>&1 |grep libstdc++
   1926528: find library=libstdc++.so.6 [0]; searching
   1926528:   trying file=/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shiboken2/libstdc++.so.6
   1926528:   trying file=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   1926528: calling init: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   1926533: find library=libstdc++.so.6 [0]; searching
   1926533:   trying file=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   1926533: calling init: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   1926528: calling fini: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
```

Second, the symbol "_ZdlPvm" is indeed defined in `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 |grep _ZdlPvm
00000000000a1ca0 T _ZdlPvm
00000000000a3c30 T _ZdlPvmSt11align_val_t
```

unless these two facts do not guarantee that the symbol `_ZdlPvm` is found and used, then I wonder how it can be guaranteed and how dynamic loading really works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your symbol corresponds to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)` which is a standard C++ function. No one has any idea what `designer` is doing and how it loads libraries or searches for symbols, but let me assure you that lots of C++ applications use this function without any problem. It isn't quite clear what kind of "general C++ problem" you have in mind.

Comment: Issues with dynamic (or even static) loading of libraries, and access to symbols within them, are not a "general C++ problem" at all, since such things are not covered by the C++ standard at all so are not inherent to C++.   Your problem is going to be related to your specific implementation and system settings - settings of environment variables,  what packages/versions are installed and any interactions between them.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. "No one has any idea what designer is doing" -> and I'm not expecting that because it should not matter. "... and how it loads libraries or searches for symbols" -> for this, however, you should have some idea with the provided information.  "but let me assure you that lots of C++ applications use this function without any problem" that is the whole point of this question

Comment: @Peter "since such things are not covered by the C++ standard at all so are not inherent to C++" -> by "general c++ problem", I'm not referring to the c++ standard, but rather the ecosystem around it, to which I cannot think of any reason why linking problems do not belong. " Your problem is going to be related to ..." I have listed necessary informations that I think is "related to". Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message is

```
{...}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/designer: relocation error: 
     {...}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/designer: symbol 
     _ZdlPvm version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with
      link time reference
```

Your package is linked against **its own local copy** of Qt libraries, however you are not using those (you have not added relevant directories to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). Let's see:

```
$ nm -D {...}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep _ZdlPvm
00000000003b95e0 T _ZdlPvm

$ nm -D /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep _ZdlPvm
                 U _ZdlPvm
```

Why does it care where `_ZdlPvm` is defined? Well, because there's more to the symbol than just the name. There is also symbol version. See this little `version Qt_5` part of the message?

```
$ nm --with-symbol-versions -D /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/libstdc++.so.6 | grep _ZdlPvm
00000000000d0060 T _ZdlPvm@@CXXABI_1.3.9
00000000000d1ed0 T _ZdlPvmSt11align_val_t@@CXXABI_1.3.11

$ nm --with-symbol-versions -D {...}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep _ZdlPvm
00000000003b95e0 T _ZdlPvm@@Qt_5
```

So the symbol your local `libQt5Core.so.5` defines is actually different from what `libstdc++.so.6` defines.

I tried to add the local copy of Qt to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the result was that it was not able to find Kerberos libraries. My system does not use Kerberos so they are not present. If you use a standard Linux distro like Ubuntu, you may have better luck.

To summarize, there *is* a bug in the package. If it needs to use its own copy of Qt, it should have come up with a way to actually use it out of the box, without the user having to jump through hoops. It is not a problem of C++ or any other language. It is a manifestation of a much more general problem, known as "DLL Hell".

Comment: Adding the `--with-symbol-versions` flag to `nm` will show that `libstdc++` defines something like "_ZdlPvm@@CXXABI_1.3.9" while the question is looking for a different version "Qt_5"

Comment: Indeed, the version is the tricky part. Thanks for the efforts of setting up the environment.