# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: gpiod_line_set_direction_input

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime-error, libgpiod

I am trying to compile the libgpiod tutorial with Eclipse. The program compiles fine, but when I run it I get the following error below:

**gcc Compiler and linker parameters are like this:**

```
Building file: ../src/Maax-B-C.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++ -I"/home/ubu/eclipse-workspace/Maax-B-C/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Maax-B-C.d" -MT"src/Maax-B-C.o" -o "src/Maax-B-C.o" "../src/Maax-B-C.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Maax-B-C.cpp
 
Building target: Maax-B-C
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++ -L"/home/ubu/eclipse-workspace/Maax-B-C/lib" -o "Maax-B-C"  ./src/Maax-B-C.o   -lgpiod
Finished building target: Maax-B-C
```

**Runtime error:**

```
./Maax-B-C: symbol lookup error: ./Maax-B-C: undefined symbol: gpiod_line_set_direction_input
```

other functions of the libgpiod is working well such as: gpiod_chip_open, gpiod_chip_get_line
I also tried compiling the same code in the target os, it was a success but when I run the code, I came across with same error output.

library(libgpiod.so) and gpiod.h also have functions' prototype and symbols were exported:

```
nm -D libgpiod.so | grep "gpiod_line_set_direction_input"
```

```
00000000000034c0 T gpiod_line_set_direction_input
00000000000034d0 T gpiod_line_set_direction_input_bulk
```

```
 nm -D libgpiod.so | grep "gpiod_line_request_output"
```

```
00000000000039c0 T gpiod_line_request_output
0000000000003a10 T gpiod_line_request_output_flags
```

What is your suggestion to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you built this library libgpiod yourself from source code? If yes, check if that symbol is exported properly.

Comment: Yes, I already checked and it was exported. When I import ```gpiod.h```, I can see           
 ```int gpiod_line_set_direction_input(struct gpiod_line *line); ```  Exported functions prototype.

Comment: Have you mentioned the library path? You need to explicitly mention library path if it is not in the same directory.

Comment: @kiner_shah, yeah, also library path is well, I don't think so the problem is because of the path. because I am using other functions in the library. as I mentioned in the question above.

Comment: You can use `nm` command to check if symbol is exported in the library - `nm -C libname.so | grep "gpiod_line_set_direction_input"`. If there is no output for this function, then check for some other function of your library - if there is output for other function, then the function isn't exported.

Comment: I tried as you said, that is result  ```ubu@ubu-ABRA-A7-V3:~/eclipse-workspace/Maax-B-C/lib$ nm -C libgpiod.so | grep "gpiod_line_set_direction_input"
00000000000034c0 T gpiod_line_set_direction_input
00000000000034d0 T gpiod_line_set_direction_input_bulk
ubu@ubu-ABRA-A7-V3:~/eclipse-workspace/Maax-B-C/lib$ nm -C libgpiod.so | grep "gpiod_line_request_output"
00000000000039c0 T gpiod_line_request_output
0000000000003a10 T gpiod_line_request_output_flags```               according to these outputs, getting error is weird. when I compile the code after using this func. I am still struggling

Comment: Really weird, you seem to be using Eclipse, try Clean and Build once. Also, sorry, I think the `nm` command should be `nm -D ..` see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810670

Comment: Also, "other functions of the libgpiod is working well" - this doesn't mean that library is properly linked, you are probably thinking that no errors were thrown during compilation or linking. To check if the library is properly linked, you should do `ldd` on the generated executable and see if the library is found like `ldd libname`

Comment: what do u mean exactly by linked? with what? when I use `ldd` key work.              
      `ldd /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgpiod.so: 
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffbdbcb000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffbd9fb000)
 /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffbdb9d000)`
I am getting this output above.

Comment: Apologies, I gave the wrong command earlier. Instead of using `ldd libgpiod.so` do `ldd` on your executable `ldd exectuable_name` and check if `libgpiod` is present in the output. By linked I mean if the library is linked to the exectuable.

Comment: `ldd ./Test 
        linux-vdso.so.1 
        libgpiod.so.2 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgpiod.so.2 
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 
        libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 `

Comment: lib is looking linked properly when I run the ldd.

Comment: Hmm.. Really weird, everything looks fine, not sure why you get undefined symbol error.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I am still trying to find solitions. if I find I'll share it here.

Comment: You can try running the exe with `LD_DEBUG` like `LD_DEBUG=all ./Test > ld_debug_out`, it will write a large output to the file `ld_debug_out` which you can analyze. Refer [this](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html).